# "The parameter is incorrect" when setting scan file format to PDF

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to make a UWP app that allows users to quickly set a few settings and then scan a document.  One of the settings I want to give the user is to choose between a Tiff or a PDF.  When I set the file format to PDF which is in the enum list of File Formats you can set to a scanner configuration I am getting an exception thrown.  The exception is "The parameter is incorrect"

Other applications are able to scan as a PDF with my type of scanner (Fujitsu fi-6130) but my application will not, I even tried a long shot of making sure my locally installed Adobe was up to date not that I thought those two would interact. When I set the format to a Tiff, or png I do not get any error and they scan no problem.

I have followed the documentation to configure a scanner correctly and PDF is listed as an available Format here [ImageScannerFormat Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.scanners.imagescannerformat)

```
// MyScanner is an instance of ImageScanner class
MyScanner.FeederConfiguration.Format = ImageScannerFormat.Pdf;
```

It fails at this line, not when I try to scan files, Tiff, PNG, and Bitmap have all worked, not sure about the other available format because I have not tested them.

I expect the scanner to accept PDF as a file format and to then scan the files as a PDF.

Let me know if you have any questions, thanks!

Comment: What's the result if you run the following method to detect pdf format: [IImageScannerFormatConfiguration.IsFormatSupported(ImageScannerFormat) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.scanners.iimagescannerformatconfiguration.isformatsupported)

Comment: It is returning false, do you know what the contingencies for scanning as PDF are.  Other applications are able to scan as a PDF with the scanner I am using.  I would rather not have to convert it to a PDF from Tiff if possible.

Comment: I cannot be sure of this, maybe you should check whether you've installed the latest driver first. Also as UWP scanner API is using [WIA driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wia/-wia-startpage), you can contact your scanner vendor to know whether they know anything about this.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. I will check up with Fujitsu. I know I have a WIA driver installed but it still doesn't support it. Thanks for your time.